# Where can I find a single web page with all elements that are usable in an Android layout file?

Tags: android, xml

I found an [invaluable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) that has--on ONE page--every element that can be used in `Manifest.xml`, with the HUGE plus that every element is linked to detailed info about itself. Here's an edited version of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission        />
    <permission             />
    <permission-tree        />
    <permission-group       />
    <instrumentation        />
    <uses-sdk               />
    <uses-configuration     />  
    <uses-feature           />  
    <supports-screens       />  
    <compatible-screens     />  
    <supports-gl-texture    />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action     />  
                <category   />
                <data       />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data      />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>    ...
        </activity-alias>

        <service>       ...
        </service>

        <receiver>      ...
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission   />
            <meta-data              />
            <path-permission        />
        </provider>

        <uses-library       />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Click ANY token above and there's detailed help.

I can't find a similar page for layout XML files.

**Is there a web page with all elements that are usable in Android layout XML files that has links to detailed info about each element?**

(I have found lots of helpful examples, but there's no substitute for a complete reference whenever available. With examples you're forced to depend on the author's explanation, which has to omit most details.)

(Maybe my limited experience with Android is preventing me from seeing how huge such a file would be and thus couldn't exist.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

If you click on the `57 others` in the `Indirect Subclasses` section, you will get all the `View`s that Android allows. (or the black arrow beside `Indirect Subclasses`)

Comment: @Little--well done; thanks. Added URL to Favorites. Just a bit more complex than Manifest.xml....... Boatload of stuff to sift through.

Comment: Hang on... I'm looking for XML syntax for layouts, not Java class declarations for layouts. The link is definitely valuable, but I didn't see anything about XML. Did I miss it?

Comment: Just do a browser search inside each relevant web page for android:

Comment: @DSlomer64 Android maintains two types of pages for views - documentation and tutorials. Once you know what view you wanna use, you can always search for its official tutorial :) Sounds easy? :)

Answer (score 1):

*Based largely on The Answer from LittleChild, here's what I plan to refer to and update often in hopes of learning Android layout XML...*

Android ***Layout*** **XML** Big Picture:

[Layout overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

[Layout resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html)

[View (widgets)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

[ViewGroup (layouts)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

[Widgets (classes)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html)